Can I use 24 Vdc to power or connect an MCX06C programmable control?
Can I power this MCX module using 24 Vdc?
It's originally connected to a transformer and when I check it only gives an output of 24 Vac but the module does not come ON but when I connect it to a 24 Vdc it comes up.
I want to know if I should go ahead to power it with the 24 Vdc for usage.


Have you asked the manufacturer?

The title of the question contains MCX06VC. I found MCX06C on the Danfoss site which looks like the same product as shown in the picture. However, I'm not sure if the  MCX06C is a different product or if MCX06VC in the title was a typo.

MCX06VC was a typo from me

The Danfoss manufacturer product page is Program. controller, 6 relays, MCX06C.
The Product details contains the following which suggests will operate from an AC or DC supply::


Supply voltage [V] AC   24 V
Supply voltage [V] DC   24 V


However, the Installation guide contains the following in the Technical Specifications which gives different voltages for AC and DC supplies:

POWER SUPPLY

20/60 V DC and 24 V AC ± 15% 50/60 Hz SELV. Maximum power consumption: 6 W, 9 VA
Insulation between power supply and the extra-low voltage: functional


From the question:

I want to know if I should go ahead to power it with the 24 Vdc for usage.

While the device probably has a bridge rectifier at its input which allows a AC or DC input supply, suggest that contact the manufacturer to determine if will operate reliably at 24 V DC, rather than the lower 20 V DC suggested in in the installation guide.

Thank you, I have sent an email to them.
